# Node.js url route formatting

Tags: node.js, rest, url, routes, express

I am coding a REST API using restify node.js.

Right now I am doing like this:

```
"http://test.com/products/query/keyword"  

Routing = server.get('products/query/:keyword', myCallBack);
```

And getting the params like `req.pramams.keyword`

I want to get params like :

```
"http://test.com/products/?query=keyword"
 Routing ?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `req.query` object:

```
// if you use Express (as your tags seem to suggest)
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

app.get('/products/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Query sent: ' + req.query.query);
});

app.listen(3012);
```

```
// if you use Restify (as your text seems to suggest)
var restify = require('restify');
var app     = restify.createServer();

app.pre(restify.pre.sanitizePath()); // necessary to be able to use /products/
                                     // (with trailing slash)
app.use(restify.queryParser());

app.get('/products/', function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.query.query);
});

app.listen(3012);
```